# Float first li item to the left maintaining all other items to right

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to move the first li item to the left while all the others stay on the right. Can't understand why float: left does not work. Could you please explain what I'm doing wrong? This seemed the most effective way to achieve what I want to.

HTML

```
    <header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">@</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
 *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

nav {
    background-color: rgba(3, 4, 94, 1);
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;  
} 

li:first-child {
    float: left;
}

li {
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 0rem 3rem 0rem 3rem;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    padding: 2.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 180, 216, 1)
}
```

Comment: Float does not work in a flex container

Comment: Just give the first item margin right auto

Comment: Thanks! So I guess I have two more questions: why does float not work in a flex container? When one is supposed to use it? And why margin auto?

Comment: Can't answer you why float doesn't work but margin-right: auto; will use all of the remaining space in the parent as margin

Comment: Another method to get it like this is to put justify-self: flex-start; on the elements you want on the left side

Answer (score 0):

```
li:first-child {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: justify-self flex start does not work in this case.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer to provide more detail. Specifically, it would be helpful if you explained how this solves the problem - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26661973)